# What does “Mitt Romney pretends to be a Nascar, cheesy-grits guy” mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context

In New York Times (March 17) article titled, “Is Elvis a Mormon?” Maureen Dowd criticizes Mitt Romney as his manner being so “inauthentic.” She says:

> “You can’t find him anywhere. Is he the guy he was on Wednesday or the guy he was on Thursday?”

and then,

> “Mitt works overtime pretending he’s *a Nascar, cheesy-grits guy* and masking his pride in his bank account and faith.”

To me, Nascar is the abbreviation of the National Association for Stock Car Auto Racing. Does this mean he enjoys car racing as a racing driver?

As for cheesy –grits, www.mrfoodcom defines it as “a recipe for classic down-home cheese grits is chock-full of sharp Cheddar cheese.”

What does Mitt Romney pretends to be *a Nascar, cheesy-grits guy*? What do “a Nascar” and “Cheesy-grits” symbolize? Is Dowd trying to say Romney wants to be seen by voters, just as a commonplace person and a docile husband, not a plutocratic politician?

Comment: You do love asking about the obscure flowery metaphors Dowd uses when writing about politicians! I'm sure she just means exactly the associations you surmise. Millionaire Romney tries (unsuccessfully) to come across as just an ordinary guy who likes junk food snacks and stock car racing. Because there are a lot of Americans like that, and he wants them to vote for him because he's "just like them". Or maybe there aren't *any* like that, but everyone thinks if there *was* such a person, they'd vote for him as a [good ole boy](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/good+ole+boy)

Comment: @FumbleFingers. Thanks for your precious input always. Though I’m not a Dowd’s fan, her “flowery” expressions and Maureen brand coinage are amusing as well as challenging to non-native speakers like me. Her articles also provide me with fodders for keeping EL&U posting. Whenever I’m out of stock of English language related topics, I would fish for materials in her NYT column and get them pretty often.

Comment: haha I can certainly see they would be "challenging". But you must be careful not to start talking/writing like her - the language of political journalists/pundits is a language all of its own! I sometimes wish you'd take out a subscription to [New Scientist](http://www.newscientist.com/) instead of The New York Times and Time Magazine!

Comment: Also, Dowd is a partisan hack who should be ignored at every opportunity.  :-)

Comment: @Yoichi Oishi: Thanks for the kind words, but I must just say describing my input as *"precious"* is actually rather **precious** phrasing (you'll have to ask another question if you're not sure what I mean by that! :). A more common phrasing would be *"your [highly-]valued input"*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers. I really meant your input is highly valuable by “precious.” I have an old memory that I went into rapture when the head of the ad agency I worked for introduced me to a new client who happen to be Brit by saying “This man is a precious asset of our agency.” Having your comment, I checked an English dictionary at hand and was shocked to find out the word, “precious” has other meanings of “exaggerated, pompous, terrible, and worthless,” which I was totally ignorant of. I trust you didn’t take that way. But thanks again for your valuable input. I’ll be mindful of using “precious.”

Comment: @Yoichi Oishi: We've interacted here enough that I would always assume a language problem, nothing more! I only really said it so I could make a feeble pun on another meaning of the word, but I don't think your agency head spoke clumsily. In a relatively formal context like that, only the primary sense would be intended and understood - you were given praise indeed, which I'm sure was both heartfelt and fully justified!

Comment: @FumbleFingers I would recommend to him a supscription to the *Economist*. There’s been some interesting work on its language. —— I took your meaning of ***precious*** to be the OED3’s sense 3: “Aiming at or affecting refinement in manners, language, etc.; fastidious, particular. Now usu. *depreciative*: over-delicate, over-fastidious; affectedly refined in matters of taste, language, etc.” :)

Comment: @tchrist: That was indeed my primary intended meaning - but also (possibly just local idiom round my way) synonym for [priceless](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/priceless) as *"amusing, odd"*, particularly of something done by someone unwittingly.

Comment: There's nothing whatsoever obscure about "NASCAR fan" or "NASCAR demographic", it's a shorthand for "blue-collar, southern US, [typically adult, 63% male, 75% white, 50% no-college-education](https://partners.lfr95.com/the-state-of-the-nascar-fan-and-what-it-means-for-sponsorship-in-2020), leans Republican" demographic, whether in US politics or more broadly. @FumbleFingers. And of course it means "fan" not "driver". And as to Maureen Dowd and her paymasters and the target audience of her piece and whether it was unfair, whatever.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[image] [image]

...apparently that's what them [good ole boys](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/good+ole+boy) down in Texas eat when they get back from an afternoon at the stock car racing. Mitt Romney - just an ordinary guy like all the voters (except he has a bit more money than most of them!)

EDIT: The question has arisen in comments as to exactly how Dowd's phrasing represents **stereotyping**. I'm a Brit who's never been to a stock car race or eaten "grits" - or even heard of *NASCAR* and *"cheesy grits"* before. Nevertheless, I grasped the sense immediately.

To my mind that makes it axiomatically a "stereotype", even if the specific referents used to invoke it are unknown to me (and probably never used in that conjunction before by any other writer in history). It's true Romney recently went to a stock car racing event (he fluffed *that* by saying his interest in the sport was proven by the fact that one of his friends *owned* a racing team). And he recently claimed he liked eating "grits" (a dish strongly associated with poor Southerners, and about as likely as Bill Gates tucking into [Pot Noodle/Cup o' Noodles](http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20080928053133AAnEFw4) every night).

As a "journalist/media pundit", Dowd wouldn't want her words open to being challenged on *factual* grounds, but the average reader doesn't need to know or care whether the specific allusions have any basis in Romney's recent activities. All that matters is we understand Dowd to be saying Romney falsely claims to be a stereotypical *ordinary guy* just like those whose votes he seeks.

Answer (score 13):

Maureen Dowd is basically accusing Mitt of pandering to southern voters by pretending to like the same things they do:  NASCAR and cheesy grits, both of which are stereotypically southern sorts of things.

Answer (score 5):

> Is Dowd trying to say Romney wants to be seen by voters, just as a commonplace person and a docile husband, not a plutocratic politician?

Well, I don't know about "docile husband," but yes, Dowd is saying that Romney is pretending to be an average guy, which is supposedly someone who *watches* Nascar races and eats grits. Both of these are references to recent events: just picking the first hits on Google for "romney nascar" and "romney grits" gives [the Atlantic](http://www.theatlanticwire.com/politics/2012/02/romneys-nascar-comment-rich/49185/) and [the Boston Herald](http://bostonherald.com/news/us_politics/view/20220313romneys_grits_and_catfish_act_goes_too_far_for_southern_critics).

Comment: This is the correct answer because the quote is referencing specific events for Romney, rather than general stereotypes.

Comment: @smackfu: I don't see what you mean. OP didn't instantly pick up on the stereotype because it's too far removed from his cultural background. But I'm a Brit who's never been to a stock car race or eaten "grits" - or even *heard* of NASCAR and "cheesy grits" before. Nevertheless, I grasped the sense immediately. To my mind that makes it axiomatically a "stereotype", even if the specific referents used to invoke it are unknown to me (and probably never used in that conjunction before by any other writer in history).

Comment: @FumbleFingers: I was thinking more along this part of the question "What do “a Nascar” and “Cheesy-grits” symbolize?", and that they don't as such symbolize anything since they are referring to specific events.  I do agree that the author could have used the same words to talk about another candidate and they would symbolize something, so... I'm not sure if it's a necessary distinction, as such.

Comment: @smackfu: Yes, I also mulled over how importance it was that those two referents be well-known (individually or as a pairing), and/or actually *true*. I've expanded my answer having decided the first is largely irrelevant so long as we catch the drift, and the second is only important from Dowd's point of view so she can easily defend her particular choice of (in practice, "metaphoric") references.

Comment: @smackfu.Certainly the word “symbolize” doesn’t seem to fit to the attributes for characterizing Romney. Instead, I should have said “What do “a Nascar” and “Cheesy-grits” signify, (or refer to)?”

Comment: @Yoichi Oishi: No no - Dowd specifically says Romney is *pretending* he's such a person. But neither she nor her readers are ever going to believe this. She's poking fun at Romney's futile attempts to convince people of something so obviously untrue. That's why it doesn't matter to us the readers exactly what that stereotype represents. All she wants us to recognise is that Romney is a fake, but she chooses those two aspects because she knows he's recently messed up with them. They are *not* an "established stereotype" pairing.

Answer (score 5):

Essentially, Dowd is invoking a stereotype - one that she believes Romney would like to emulate, possibly to get more votes.

NASCAR, the auto racing sport you mention, experienced a surge in popularity about 10 years ago.  Even though NASCAR fans can be found from all walks of life, the stereotypical NASCAR fan is "true red, white, and blue," meaning blue collar, and patriotic.  It's considered a "redneck" sport, and has a relatively huge following in the south (which, incidentally, is where grits is a popular food staple).

On the surface, Romney is everything your cliché NASCAR fan is not: Romney is a wealthy Mormon from the North.  In her remarks, Dowd is claiming that Romney is trying to bridge the gap between his elitist background, and that of the typical NASCAR fan, by pretending to have common interests - and she is doing so with very vivid, colloquial language.

> Note to everyone: I'm going to stick with English, and stay out of
>   politics.  I'm not endorsing or criticizing Romney as a candidate, nor
>   am I agreeing or disagreeing with Dowd's assessment.  Most politicians
>   don a veneer of some sort, and political columnists have
>   criticized such politicians - rightly or wrongly - for generations.
>   I'm only explaining what Dowd was trying to say, and I won't comment
>   on the accuracy or inaccuracy of her appraisal.

Answer (score 4):

This means Mitt Romney pretends to be a working-class guy. Watching NASCAR races and eating cheesy-grits are things associated with the American working class, particularly the working class of the American South.